# Ajax deleted items are shown after refreshing the page

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, jquery

Hi i am new in rails and i am using rails 3.My que is i want to delete an image from the list using ajax. When i click on delete button, image is still visible on the index page, however actually it gets deleted but user can see changes after refreshing the web page. I want it visible on the same page as the ajax is used for. Any one please help. Thank you...

My code for controller is:

```
def destroy
  logger.info params[:event].inspect
  @event = Event.find(params[:id])
  @event.destroy
  #redirect_to events_url
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to @event, :notice => 'Event deleted' }
    format.js
  end
end
```

My code for view is:

```
**app/view/events/index.html.haml**
    - @events.each do |event|
      %ol.hoverbox
        %li.all{:id =>"event_#{event.id}"}
          = link_to image_tag(event.photo.url), event_path(event)
          .abc
            = event.name
            %br/ 
          .bca
            = event.start_date 
            |
            = event.start_time
            |
            = link_to "&nbsp;".html_safe, event_path(event), :remote => true, :method => :delete, :class => "del-16", :confirm=>"Are u sure?", :title => "Delete", :style => "text-decoration:none;"
```

code for js is:

```
*destroy.js.erb*
$("#event_#{event.id}").fadeOut().remove();
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to look at [here](http://railscasts.com/episodes/136-jquery)

write something like this

**$("#event_#{event.id}").reset();** in your **destroy.js.erb** file.

I hope this would help you.

Thanks.

Comment: hey urjit thanks for suggestion,i followed the method but still i am facing the same problem.

Comment: ok, Delete the $("#event_#{event.id}").reset();      
and please try the following code      
$("#event_#{event.id}").fadeOut(700); remove .remove() from fadeOut.

Comment: i think there is some problem in calling destroy.js.erb file because when i am writing alert(ajax works); in the js file this is also not working.

Comment: you should either use .remove() or .fadeOut(); not both in one .
If you think js is not calling then use alert(); in the file and test.

Comment: https://github.com/markusproske/ajax_demo/tree/jquery show this link this is example.

Comment: hey i wrote $('##{dom_id(@event)}').remove(); in my js file now it is working.., thnks for help..... :D

Comment: yes..i took little reference from this site http://www.communityguides.eu/articles/15.. and some from beginning rails book